# What is the major difference between Series.index and Series.key() ? They return the exact same result

Tags: python, pandas, series

I tried Series.index and Series.keys() and the output was similar. I can't find a notable difference in them. Are they meant for some special conditions?

I used them on Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda, Pandas version 0.24.2.

Code:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2.5, '3', 'Hello', "Series Tutorial", 'random text', np.nan])

s1.index
```

Output: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=7, step=1)

```
s1.keys()
```

Output: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=7, step=1)

Comment: [`keys`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.keys.html) is just an alias. They're identical

Comment: One is a property and other is a function? I guess this exists for places where you are expected to provide a function (spares you a `lambda x: x.index`).

Comment: see [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.0/pandas/core/series.py#L1733-L1742): `def keys(self):` `return self.index`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference. keys() is an alias for index.
Search for 'Alias for index' under documentation: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.html

Comment: So the word 'index' in "Alias for index" means the Series.index function and not the index of Series?

Comment: s.keys() == s.index